# Tensorflow error: TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the error "TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type " when I run the following codes:

```
loss, critic_params = net.train(x1, x2, y)
```

Here is my network defintion:

```
self.online_trainable_weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="c_hot")
# Note: the self.loss here is just a common squared error.
self.weights_grads = tf.gradients(self.loss, self.online_trainable_weights)
self.weights_grad_clipped, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(self.weights_grads, 5.0)
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr_start)
grads_and_vars = zip(self.weights_grad_clipped, self.online_trainable_weights)
self.optimize_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)

def train(self, x1, x2, y):
    loss, params, _ = self.sess.run([self.loss, self.check_params, self.optimize_op], feed_dict={
    self.hot_in_s: x1,
    self.hot_in_a: x2,
    self.y: y
    })
    return loss, params
```

I notice this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114832/tensorflow-typeerror-fetch-argument-none-has-invalid-type-type-nonetype) ask the same question, but the above codes seems do the same thing as the answer since I assign `self.optimize_op` to `_`.

Note: my tensorflow version is 0.12.1

EDIT:
Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 182, in <module>
    main(params)
  File "main.py", line 118, in main
    loss, actor_params, critic_params = agent.train(batch, total_steps)
  File "/home/ld/code_base/drl/new_experiment/ddpg_torcs_v3.0/agent.py", line 61, in train
    loss, critic_params = self.net.train(x1, x2, y)  # 1.42s
  File "/home/ld/code_base/drl/new_experiment/ddpg_torcs_v3.0/critic.py", line 152, in train
    self.y: y
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 951, in _run
fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 407, in __init__
self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in __init__
self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in __init__
self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in __init__
self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/home/ld/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 227, in for_fetch
(fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: When writing the information about the error, it is useful to post the complete traceback. That gives context and saves the reader from guessing where the error occurred.

Comment: Seems like one of these is `None`: `[self.loss, self.check_params, self.optimize_op]`

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Yes, it's the `self.check_params`. And the actually reason is use of BatchNormalization layer : )