# Encounter Errors When Using tensorflow.summary

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm learning  *TensorFlow* by try out the example mnist_softmax.py ([this is the orignal file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py)),I add a few modification to it in order to using *TensorBoard*:

```
   tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
  summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('mnist_logs', sess.graph)
  # Train
  for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    if i%25 == 0:
        summary_str , _  =  sess.run(merged_summary_op)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str,i)

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                      y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

but a got errors when I run this file:

```
 File "mnist_softmax.py", line 87, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "mnist_softmax.py", line 73, in main
    summary_str , _  =  sess.run(merged_summary_op)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1109, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 413, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I will be highly appreciated if someone can find out where I write wrong:).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is the same: [Tensorflow TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114832/tensorflow-typeerror-fetch-argument-none-has-invalid-type-type-nonetype)

Although it's not shown in your code, the value of variable `train_step` is probably `None`. Print that out and check. That is your "fetch argument", it's the OP or tensor you are asking tensorflow to compute and return to you.

Somewhere earlier in your code you probably have:

`train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(...).minimize(...)`

Tensorflow needs you to send this OP (operation) to `sess.run(...)`. This instructs tensorflow to compute the `train_step` "OP", and in doing so updates the weights. Somewhere along the way `train_step` probably got reassigned to `None`.